# Ignoring old UDP packets Python

Tags: python, performance, sockets, networking, udp

I am writing code for a system that communicates via Wifi that consists of an Android device sending UDP packets through a router to a Raspberry Pi. The information being sent is very time critical, and as a way to improve performance I am trying to write python code for the Pi to ignore old packets if there is a more recent one in the buffer (the data indicates the state of a control interface - the older data is useless). Since the Pi has limited processing power, I want to avoid doing extra work on old data. The code is currently as follows:

```
import time
import socket

#This section of code creates the socket and shows that it is running
UDP_IP = ''
UDP_PORT = 2016
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while(1):
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) #receives UDP packets, buffer size is 1024 bytes
    # do time critical stuff with data
```

I know with SOCK_DGRAM that if I set the buffer size to 8 (the number of bytes in the data being sent in) it will only bring in 8 bytes and discard the rest - would this accomplish my goal, or would this bring in the oldest 8 bytes, or have some other behavior?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

"would this bring in the oldest 8 bytes?" Yes because the queue is implemented as a [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)), one which is sent earlier is on the front part of the queue, thus leaving sooner.
One way to handle this issue is to create yourself a so-called protocol that attaches the time in which data is created in the client to the packet being sent. This way you can ignore packets that are outdated based on your own criteria. on the clinet:

```
from datetime import datetime
packet = b'{}:some data'.format(datetime.now())
```

Comment: I thought that was the case. I'll try that solution. Thanks for your help!